# Firefox error occurs when use quit function of selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, exit

I'm trying to run a python script that imports selenium (using firefox browser).
I tried `close()`.. but it's not working.. window remains the same
after the script I want to close firefox window, so I use `driver.quit()` and it succeeded to close the window, but it gives me an error like (I tried to attach an image, but I failed... so will just provide a text that error window contains)

> The exception Breakpoint A breakpoint has been reached. (0x80000003)
>   occurred in the application at location 0x73xe9ec83.
>
> Click on OK to terminate the program

And I think there are some people go through the same problem but can't find a solution....
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known Firefox/geckodriver issue with quitting driver, see [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/173) for more details.

It appears in some FF versions, some say it's fixed, some say it's not. I couldn't find better solution for this so I switched on 'old' Firefoxdriver and FF v47.0.2 which works fine.

Comment: Oh... Thank you so much. I appreciate your help :)